# Java command line could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, bash

I have been trying to run any .class file from the command line, and I keep getting this error. After trying to figure out the problem on my own all night, i'm officially stumped.

I'm on linux, and I use eclipse usually so my .java file and .class file are in two different locations.

Heres classpath....

```
%> echo $CLASSPATH
/home/mike/Documents/java
```

Heres one of my .class directories...

```
/home/mike/Documents/java/homework/bin/src
```

Heres the corresponding .java directory...

```
/home/mike/Documents/java/homework/src/src
```

Heres what I enter in bash...

```
[ mike (23:31:16): ~] $ >java homework.bin.src.EulerMath
```

OR

```
[ mike (23:32:41): ~/Documents/java] $ >java -cp . homework.bin.src.EulerMath
```

OR

```
[ mike (23:34:08): ~/Documents/java/homework/bin/src] $ >java -cp . EulerMath
```

All give me the same error. Obviously im trying to run EulerMath.class, which is within the package src. This compiles and runs fine within eclipse, and I have a similar issue with every other program i try to run from the command line. I can compile the .java file with javac but when trying to run the new .class file i get this error. Id appreciate any help

Comment: Have you compiled the .java file?

Comment: Is `EulerMath` in a package (what is the first non-commented line of `EulerMath`)? The package name is part of the class in Java. The directory structure is not meaningless.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, using both javac command and eclipse


ElliotFrisch yes, as stated above it is in the src package and that is included in my commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `CLASSPATH` like

```
export CLASSPATH="$HOME/Documents/java/homework/bin"
```

then you can run it without a `-cp` command line like

```
java src.EulerMath
```

Without setting the `CLASSPATH` (or if you want to override the set `CLASSPATH`) you can do

```
java -cp $HOME/Documents/java/homework/bin src.EulerMath
```

But `src.EulerMath` is the name of your class. Alternatively, you can package it in a jar file with some meta-information (basically a [`Main-Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)) and run it with `java -jar <jarfile.jar>`

Comment: i have already modified CLASSPATH in ~/.bashrc, where i modified my PATH as well. The CLASSPATH var reflects this change.

Comment: @mike Note that the CLASSPATH I have provided here matches where you said your classes are (namely `src/EulerMath.class` is in `/home/mike/Documents/java/homework/bin`). Your question says you set it to `/home/mike/Documents/java/homework/bin/src`; note the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the class (Note: not run it yet, i got a new error but thats a different story). Hopefully this helps someone else

Somewhere along these steps it fixed itself:

- make sure CLASSPATH is correct
- install javac
- use javac on file
- reboot computer

should work now