# java class executing on Eclipse but not in command line

Tags: java, executable, javac

My java class files run in Eclipse but not in command line. I have tried all possible solutions. My code has the following structure:

```
Client_1/src/filedownload/Client.java

RMI_interface/src/filedownload/Hello.java
```

The `Client.java` file is dependent on `Hello.java`. `filedownload` is the name of package.
When I compile using the following command, it works.

```
javac RMI_interface/src/filedownload/Hello.java Client_1/src/filedownload/Client.java
```

But when I execute the class file in the `Client_1/src` folder using following command, it does not work.

```
java filedownload.Client
```

The error displayed is

```
Could not find or load main class
```

I have tried many posts on stackoverflow but I am unable to solve it. I am using ubuntu.

The code structure is

```
package filedownload;
import ....
public class Client implements Hello, Runnable{
...other functions.....
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{

}
}
```

Comment: Do you set classpath? Take a look at these : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448151/java-command-line-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: You should `java` in `Client_1/src/filedownload` not in `Client_1/src`.

Comment: I tried from Client_1/src/filedownload but it did not work.

Comment: Can you post the code of both classes?

Comment: It is not possible to post the code since it is a project submission but I can share relevant sections of the code.

Comment: Please share especially the main method.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Client class have the main() method ?  Where are the .class files after compilation (that is, what's the current directory you're executing the compile from) ?  What's the current directory when you try to execute ?  What's the classpath when you try to execute ?

Without all that info, there's little chance of anyone being able to get you going (but for the obvious advice of just setting up eclipse and doing everything from within eclipse - letting eclipse take care of all the nitty gritty detail).

(And the questions themselves suggest various possible points of failure in your scenario so *look* at it.)

Comment: my Client class has a main(). I am executing from Client_1/src folder. Class files reside in Client_1/src/filedownload and RMI_interface/src/filedownload. I am using the following command from Client/src folder :java filedownload.Client.

Comment: From Oracle docs : "The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is searched. Specifying either the CLASSPATH variable or the -cp command line switch overrides this value."  Note "overrides this value".  Check if you have a CLASSPATH variable set by trying "echo $CLASSPATH" in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

All your steps seems to be correct. You didn't share the `Client.java` code which has `main` method.
Make sure you follow this `main` method syntax:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  ...
}
```

E.g. if you write `main` without `args`, it can't be found.

Comment: My main method has args.

Comment: You gotta share some code buddy for us to help you better.

Comment: Are you overriding `run` method in `Client` class?

Comment: Ok remove the Runnable as insterface. There's no need. And then delete, recompile, and run again.

Comment: I am using the run() function but what I mean is that I did not provide @Override above run() function.

Comment: Add that annotation

Comment: it throws error in eclipse. It says "Hello" needs to have a function run()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169779/discussion-between-shanu-gupta-and-user8109).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your classes in a separate folder, separated from your sources.

```
javac -d bin RMI_interface/src/filedownload/Hello.java Client_1/src/filedownload/Client.java
```

(folder 'bin' must exist already)
And inside folder 'bin' execute command:

```
java filedownload.Client
```